# Bad 'numberprecision' has been ignored

Tags: metapost

I just read that it's possible to run METAPOST with a binary numbersystem (`mpost -numbersystem binary`) and that it's possible to specify the number of bits by assigning a value to the variable `numberprecision`.

If I try `numberprecision := 64` I get the following error:

> ! Bad 'numberprecision' has been ignored.

I tried googling for a solution but got zero hits.

FWIW, I'm using version 1.902.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also posted this question on comp.text.tex, which is where Stephan Hennig wrote that it looks like 'binary' is not yet part of the MetaPost in TL 2014. (The TL 2014 METAPOST manual *does* refer to the `numberprecision` variable...)

I decided to post this as an answer, so I can close the question.

Answer (score 5):

The changelog at https://foundry.supelec.fr/frs/shownotes.php?release_id=413 says:

```
New internal: 'numberprecision', for use with 'the 'decimal' number
  system. The (numeric) value expresses the desired calculation precision, 
  in decimal places.

  system  default   min    max
  ============================
  scaled       10    10     10  (assignment effectively ignored)
  double       16    16     16  (assignment effectively ignored)
  decimal      34     1   1000
```

so it doesn't sound as if you can use it together with the number system "binary".

Comment: Seems like it. It looks like `binary` is interpreted as `double`. One can show the `numberprecision` to the log, and get `16`. Might be an idea to write to the metapost list, not sure if Taco read TS.

Comment: It's Luigi Scarso who maintains MetaPost now, by the way. I would advise to write to the MetaPost Mailing list as well.

Comment: Thanks @UlrikeFisher, and sorry about the delay in getting back (I'm having an easy time without access to interner). See my answer to my own question for an explanation.